# General error: 1364 Field 'identifier' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('identifier')->unique();
    $table->string('username')->unique();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('avatar');
    $table->string('trade')->nullable();
    $table->decimal('funds')->default(0);
    $table->enum('visibility', [1, 2, 3]);
    $table->uuid('api_token');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and

```
User::updateOrCreate([
    'identifier' => 'dasdasd',
    'username' => $user->nickname,
    'name' => $user->name,
    'avatar' => $user->avatar,
    'visibility' => $user->visibility,
    'api_token' => Uuid::generate()
]);
```

Results: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'identifier' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Guilherme Araújo, 2017-03-26 20:39:04, 2017-03-26 20:39:04))

What is wrong?

Comment: Is the identifier really 'dasdasd' or is that just for the code example? Because in your schema you define it as a unique integer, but 'dasdasd' is  a string, so that value will give an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should generate an unique integer for the `identifier` field:

```
'identifier' => 12345,
```

And since you're using `updateOrCreate()` you should add `identifier` to the `$fillable` array:

```
protected $fillable = ['identifier', ....];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your variable identifier is user fillable, then it must be filled with an integer value.